# Apache Httpclient and the Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, httpclient, cloud-foundry, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to put a scraping service using Apache HttpClient to the Cloud. I read problems are possible with Google App Engine, as it's direct network access and threads creation are prohibited. What's about other cloud hosting providers? Have anyone experince with Apache HttpClient + cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to create threads and access other websites from CloudFoundry, you're just time limited for each process. For example, if you take a look at http://rack-scrape.cloudfoundry.com/, it's a simple rack application that inspects the 'a' tags from Google.com;

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'hpricot'

run Proc.new { |env| 

  doc = Hpricot(open("http://www.google.com"))
  anchors = (doc/"a")

  [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, [anchors.inspect]]
}
```

As for Apache HttpClient, I have no experience of this but I understand it isn't maintained any more.

Answer (score 2):

AppEngine has [threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager) and [direct network access](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) (HTTP only). There is a [workaround to make it work with HttpClient](http://peterkenji.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-apache-httpclient-4-with-google.html).

Also, if you plan to use many parse tasks in parallel, you might check out [Task Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview) or even [mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).

Btw, there is a "misfeature" in GAE that you can not fully set custom User-agent header on your requests - GAE always adds "AppEngine" to the end of it (this breaks requests to certain sites - most notably iTunes).